# bootstrap 2.3.2 navbar inside elements become invisible after first collapse only on Chrome mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-2

i have this very strange problem with bootstraps navbar 2.3.2.

this problems also happens on their official page:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/starter-template.html
```

the navbar works fine on desktops.

on mobiles on every web browser i checked every thing seems to work just fine.

the problem only occurs on chrome mobile.

on clicking the menu for the first time every thing is shown and OK.

when collapsing it back and then clicking again to see the menu suddenly the inside elements become invisible. if you will rotate your phone suddenly they will appear again.

again, this haapens only on chrome mobile exactly as it happens on the example i gave in the url.

this is very strange and i don't want to move my site to bootstrap 3.

please help me there has to be something with the css that could solve this.

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I have fixed the issue:

inside bootstrap-responsive.css:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav-collapse {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
.
.
.
.
}
```

just delete this rule inside the max-width: 480px.

:)