# Bootstrap Mobile Navigation Turns Invisible when clicked more than once. v2.3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-2

I've built a project using bootstrap 2.3.2 Ran into a few problem but with some searching and head scratched managed to find fixes for all the bugs. All except one. **"When viewing the page I have created on a mobile device, if the user clicks the MAIN MENU DROPDOWN MENU button, then closes the menu using the button, then goes to reopen the menu the menu drops down but all the links are invisible"**

**This also happens on the main Twitter Bootstrap site for version 2.3.2**, at first I thought it was an issue with either my markup or css. But it seems to be a bug with the actual framework. Has when you go to the bootstrap 3 site this is fixed.

I've done a bit a google but can not find any information regarding this bug or how to fix it. Can anyone help ? Or come across this issue before ?

Moving to bootstrap 3 at this stage would be a lot of work for me and I don't have the time. This is the only major bug left I could do with a fix.

To clarify. On a mobile device if you open the main navigation menu then close it on reopening the menu the links are invisible. They are actually there as you can click them.

**The bug only happens on mobile devices on my desktop the drop down menu works fine when I resize my browser down.**

Thanks to anyone who can shed some light.

Comment: I just tried reproducing it on my iPhone 5, but the menu works fine. This is the link I tried:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: Same problem with LG G2. Got any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
[bootstrap 2.3.2 navbar inside elements become invisible after first collapse only on Chrome mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477766/bootstrap-2-3-2-navbar-inside-elements-become-invisible-after-first-collapse-onl)

Copied from the link above:

inside bootstrap-responsive.css:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .nav-collapse {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.
.
.
. 
}
```

just delete this rule inside the max-width: 480px.