# Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 Nav collapse issue in responsive mode in chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 for one of my apps. I noticed the following issue with the collapse responsive menu, It shows properly the first time you open it However when you try it a second time the menu shows blank. This only happens on Chrome mobile browser app on the Samsung Galaxy S3.

I have attached the images for the first and second time below

[image: First time menu open]

[image: Second time open]

Comment: After a lot of digging I found another [similar question][1] which solved the matter. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477766/bootstrap-2-3-2-navbar-inside-elements-become-invisible-after-first-collapse-onl